# Docker 1.9: Adding --link target to a running nginx container

Tags: php, bash, nginx, docker

### Question:

I'm deploying on docker 1.9

I run an nginx container first:

```
docker run \
  --name=nginx \
  --link=php1:php1 \
  --link=php2:php2 \
  --restart=always \
  -p 80:80 -p 443:443 \
  -v /var/docker/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d \
  -d nginx:latest
```

Note that I linked two exist php containers: `php1` and `php2`.

Now I started a new container `php3`.

Can I add a link the `nginx` to `php3` with a single bash script on the host machine？

---

### Why I want to do this?

Because I have many different php apps to deploy, and each instance I will create a new php:fpm docker container to run the code.

And they share the same `nginx` service.

I want to make a dynamic deploy bash script for the php app, to make one-key deployment.

But I was blocked that the nginx doesn't know the newly created php host name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding link dynamically was part of [issue 3155](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3155).
Pre-libnetwork (1.9 and mainly soon 1.10), you could use [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) in order to generate the right `nginx.conf` and restart the nginx service each time a new container needs to be linked.

But with [libnetwork](https://github.com/docker/libnetwork) (and its [0.6 release early february](https://github.com/docker/libnetwork/wiki/0.6-Project-Page)), docker 1.10 comes with new [Docker networks features](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/docs/userguide/networking/index.md).

That means you will be able to attach your containers to **a user defined network**, making them automatically visible from each others by name!

```
$ docker run -itd --name=container2 busybox
498eaaaf328e1018042c04b2de04036fc04719a6e39a097a4f4866043a2c2152
```

> Then create an isolated, bridge network to test with.

```
$ docker network create -d bridge --subnet 172.25.0.0/16 isolated_nw
06a62f1c73c4e3107c0f555b7a5f163309827bfbbf999840166065a8f35455a8

$ docker run -itd --name=container2 busybox
498eaaaf328e1018042c04b2de04036fc04719a6e39a097a4f4866043a2c2152
$ docker network connect isolated_nw container2

$ docker run --net=isolated_nw --ip=172.25.3.3 -itd --name=container3 busybox
```

> The selected IP address is part of the container networking configuration and will be preserved across container reload.
>   **The feature is only available on user defined networks, because they guarantee their subnets configuration does not change across daemon reload**.
>
> On the `isolated_nw` which was user defined, the Docker embedded DNS server enables name resolution for other containers in the network.  Inside of `container2` it is possible to ping `container3` by name

What it means is, with docker 1.10, containers attached to a user-defined network can see each other by names.
But there is more: [**Linking containers in user-defined networks**](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/docs/userguide/networking/work-with-networks.md#linking-containers-in-user-defined-networks)

```
$ docker run --net=isolated_nw -itd --name=container4 --link container5:c5 busybox
01b5df970834b77a9eadbaff39051f237957bd35c4c56f11193e0594cfd5117c
```

> With the help of `--link`, `container4` will be able to reach `container5` using the aliased name `c5` as well.
>
> **Please note that while creating `container4`, we linked to a container named `container5` which is not created yet.**
>   That is one of the differences in behavior between the legacy link in default bridge network and the new link functionality in user defined networks.
>
> **- The legacy link is static in nature and it hard-binds the container with the alias and it doesn't tolerate linked container restarts.
>
>   - While the new link functionality in user defined networks are dynamic in nature and supports linked container restarts including tolerating ip-address changes on the linked container.**

---

You will have in the new docker 1.10 have two choices:

- either have a fixed NGiNX config making reverse-proxy to a fixed list of potentially not created yet containers `c1`, `c2`, `c3`... 
  Each time a new container is created, you relaunch your NGiNX container with the appropriate link: `--link c2:myNewContainer2`
- Or your NGiNX container main process actually monitors the user defined network, and for each new container detected, regenerate the NGiNX conf, and gracefully restart the NGiNX daemon.

Comment: I have an idea: what if I run `docker exec` to the nginx container and manually update the `/etc/hosts` file? Is there any problem?

Comment: @fish_ball It is not a problem, except that it is not what `docker exec` is for: it is for debugging only. Ideally, your config is mounted in the image, you change it from your host and send a graceful restart signal (from your host to the container): `sudo docker kill –signal=”USR1″ myNGiNXcontainer`. See https://medium.com/@gchudnov/trapping-signals-in-docker-containers-7a57fdda7d86#.adny3orjx and https://kuldeeparya.wordpress.com/2015/01/17/docker-how-to-restart-a-service-running-in-docker-container/ (the latter is for Apache, but the same idea applies to NGiNX)